# Add tooltip to abbreviated data table names

Tags: r, dataframe, dt, abbreviation

How can you add a tool tip to column header in a data table display

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({
    df <- iris
    colnames(df) <- sapply(names(df), function(x) abbreviate(x))
    df
})
```

The actual data frame i'm using (which I can't show) has very long names and there are >20 columns.  So abbreviating is necessary to show the entire data frame with minimal horizontal scrolling.  I'm looking for a way to add a hover over tool tip that shows the full, un-abbreviated name of each column when you hover over an abbreviated column header.

Comment: Just fyi, `abbreviate` is vectorized

Comment: My abbreviate is actually more complex than above: `abbreviate(unlist(strsplit(x, "[.]"))[2], 9)`  because i'm only interested in the part of the name after a period

Comment: I'm guessing the DT tag is relevant. Correct it if I'm wrong. Anyway, DataTable is not a thing in vanilla R.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a data table.  It can just be a data frame.  If it only works with a data frame then the app can handle the dependencies.

Comment: There is not a straightforward way to do it. You can certainly use JavaScript to achieve it, but it will be a little challenging if you are not familiar with JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

```
dat <- iris[1:3,]
names(dat) <- c(
  "A long name", 
  "Another long name",
  "Yet another long name",
  "This name is long as well",
  "This one is not short"
)

headerCallback <- c(
  "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  var ncols = data[0].length;",
  sprintf("  var shortnames = [%s]", 
          paste0(paste0("'",abbreviate(names(dat)),"'"), collapse = ",")),
  sprintf("  var tooltips = [%s];", 
          paste0(paste0("'",names(dat),"'"), collapse = ",")),
  "  for(var i=0; i<ncols; i++){",
  "    $('th:eq('+i+')',thead).attr('title', tooltips[i]).text(shortnames[i]);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

datatable(dat, rownames = FALSE, 
          options = list(
            headerCallback = JS(headerCallback)
          )
)
```

[image]